# Nuxt webapp does not start on Azure Linux App Service: container does not start within expected time limit

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, nuxt.js, azure-web-app-service

I have built a simple Nuxt app with create-nuxt-app tool. The applications uses Express.

The app is built and deployed with Azure DevOps CI/CD to a web app running on Azure in a Linux App Service. Below the JSON configuration of the Web app and the app settings.

According to the log files the application starts listening on port 8080 correctly. But the container fails to receive the ping from the application.

Here the docker command:

```
docker run -d -p 1917:8080 --name foo_0_545b2402 -e WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=12-lts -e APPSETTING_WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=12-lts -e PORT=8080 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=foo -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=foo.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=59d31c5448b1dcdbbdd17806325118df2b6bbe1ce77b2e7d81899054c843b962 -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 appsvc/node:12-lts npm run start
```

Then it keeps logging this:

```
INFO  -  Waiting for response to warmup request for container foo_0_545b2402
```

And finally logs:

```
ERROR - Container foo_0_545b2402 for site foo did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 460.1978624 sec
ERROR - Container foo_0_545b2402 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
INFO  - Stoping site foo because it failed during startup.
```

The web app trying to start the container repeats all over again without success.

I do not use custom containers and tried tweaks on changing the expose port and other docker related things I do not know. I am not a docker user.

I tried with a Node.js application with just Express and it servers the page. I guess is something related to Nuxt or the underlying Vue framework but I cannot see what.

Thanks.

Web app config:

```
{
  "alwaysOn": true,
  "apiDefinition": null,
  "apiManagementConfig": null,
  "appCommandLine": "npm run start",
  "appSettings": null,
  "autoHealEnabled": false,
  "autoHealRules": null,
  "autoSwapSlotName": null,
  "connectionStrings": null,
  "cors": null,
  "defaultDocuments": [
    "Default.htm",
    "Default.html",
    "Default.asp",
    "index.htm",
    "index.html",
    "iisstart.htm",
    "default.aspx",
    "index.php",
    "hostingstart.html"
  ],
  "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled": false,
  "documentRoot": null,
  "experiments": {
    "rampUpRules": []
  },
  "ftpsState": "AllAllowed",
  "handlerMappings": null,
  "healthCheckPath": null,
  "http20Enabled": true,
  "httpLoggingEnabled": true,  
  "ipSecurityRestrictions": [
    {
      "action": "Allow",
      "description": "Allow all access",
      "ipAddress": "Any",
      "name": "Allow all",
      "priority": 1,
      "subnetMask": null,
      "subnetTrafficTag": null,
      "tag": null,
      "vnetSubnetResourceId": null,
      "vnetTrafficTag": null
    }
  ],
  "javaContainer": null,
  "javaContainerVersion": null,
  "javaVersion": null,
  "kind": null,
  "limits": null,
  "linuxFxVersion": "NODE|12-lts",
  "loadBalancing": "LeastRequests",
  "localMySqlEnabled": false,
  "location": "North Europe",
  "logsDirectorySizeLimit": 35,
  "machineKey": null,
  "managedPipelineMode": "Integrated",
  "managedServiceIdentityId": null,
  "minTlsVersion": "1.2",
  "name": "foo",
  "netFrameworkVersion": "v4.0",
  "nodeVersion": "",
  "numberOfWorkers": 1,
  "phpVersion": "",
  "preWarmedInstanceCount": 0,
  "publishingUsername": "$foo",
  "push": null,
  "pythonVersion": "",
  "remoteDebuggingEnabled": false,
  "remoteDebuggingVersion": "VS2019",
  "requestTracingEnabled": false,
  "requestTracingExpirationTime": null,
  "resourceGroup": "alpha",
  "scmIpSecurityRestrictions": [
    {
      "action": "Allow",
      "description": "Allow all access",
      "ipAddress": "Any",
      "name": "Allow all",
      "priority": 1,
      "subnetMask": null,
      "subnetTrafficTag": null,
      "tag": null,
      "vnetSubnetResourceId": null,
      "vnetTrafficTag": null
    }
  ],
  "scmIpSecurityRestrictionsUseMain": false,
  "scmType": "LocalGit",
  "tracingOptions": null,
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
  "use32BitWorkerProcess": true,
  "virtualApplications": [
    {
      "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
      "preloadEnabled": true,
      "virtualDirectories": null,
      "virtualPath": "/"
    }
  ],
  "vnetName": "",
  "webSocketsEnabled": false,
  "windowsFxVersion": null,
  "xManagedServiceIdentityId": null
}
```

web app settings:

```
[
  {
    "name": "PORT",
    "slotSetting": false,
    "value": "8080"
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITE_HTTPLOGGING_RETENTION_DAYS",
    "slotSetting": false,
    "value": "7"
  },
  {
    "name": "WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT",
    "slotSetting": false,
    "value": "1800"
  }
]
```

Here an screenshot of the _default_docker.log:

[image: screenshot of the _default_docker.log]

Comment: Are you using a VNET?

Comment: No. At least I am not aware of. I did not explicitly create.

Comment: Which port does your application listen to?

Comment: 8080. I have added screenshot with one of the logs docker generates.

Comment: It seems there is something wrong with your application and it does not start well. So you need to check your code first.

Comment: Hi Julen, have you found the answer to your problem? I am in the exact same situation here and can't make the server render pages.

Comment: Hi Jean-Francois, sadly I did not find the solution. Truth to be told I have not work on it since the last time I wrote here.